# Nested Fragments within ViewPager have zero height and width

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-nested-fragment

I have an `Activity` with a single `Fragment` inside of it. Inside this Fragment I have a `ViewPager` that pages Fragments. This makes the paged Fragments children of the Fragment inside the Activity. Basically like this:

```
    Activity
       |
       |
    Fragment
       |
   (ViewPager)
    |       |
    |       |
Fragment  Fragment
```

Every so often, seemingly at random, the Fragments inside the ViewPager will not display. I looked at the View hierarchy in Hierarchy Viewer and noticed that when this happens the child Fragments (at the bottom of my picture) **are in the layout**, but the root View of the children has **zero height and zero width** (as does every View in the hierarchy tree from there down to the leaf Views). The `ViewPager` does have height and width, but the Fragments it pages do not.

**If I rotate the device at this point, my child Fragments show up!**

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. The Adapter I'm using with the ViewPager requires a `FragmentManager`, and I'm using the one from the Fragment inside the Activity by calling [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29). I feel like I'm doing everything I'm supposed to do, not sure where to look next on this one.

UPDATE:

Interestingly enough, if I put the code that attaches the Adapter to the ViewPager in a Runnable and post it to a Handler the issue is 100% reproducible. i.e.

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override 
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b) {
    super.onActivityCreated(b);

    runPager = new Runnable() {

      @Override 
      public void run() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

    };

    handler.post(runPager);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. If anyone else runs into this, make sure you aren't manipulating UI components on a background thread or weird things happen. In my case I was doing Bitmap manipulation on a background thread with RxJava, but I forgot this line:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

So when I put the bitmap in my View in the Subscriber, it was on a background thread. Easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with your assumption. Android is quite annoying to handle regarding the mighty `main` thread vs. `worker` threads.

For example if you trigger a `SwipeRefreshLayout` which does a network fetch, and the returning callback is invoked on the background where you just do `setRefreshing(false)` this may not show you any warning but lead to strange side effects.

If you are using child fragments inside a `ViewPager` this fragment might be working okay, but the size is reduced to `(0, 0)` or the offset of the fragments root layout is set to the screenWidth. So always doublecheck if there is a background thread accessing the user interface.

Comment: Thank You! You save my Life!!! I update come data with kotlin coroutines in Background. And some page size in (0.0). After move my code to:
GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) { ... } - problem is gone!!